# PHP - оставить уникальные в массиве по трем значениям?

Tags: php, массивы

```
Есть массив
Array ( 
[0] => 10ПП23-10 
[1] => Перемычка плитная 10 ПП 23-10 
[2] => GARANT ) 
[211] => Array ( 
[0] => 10ПП30-13 
[1] => Перемычка плитная 10 ПП 30-13 
[2] => GARANT ) 
[212] => Array ( 
[0] => 1ПБ16-1 
[1] => Перемычка плитная 10 ПП 23-10 
[2] => GARANT ) 
[213] => 
Array ( 
[0] => 10ПП23-10 
[1] => Перемычка плитная 10 ПП 23-10 
[2] => GARANT )
```

Как удалить дубли, если есть элементы с одинаковыми значениями?
На примере выше эти значения повторяются 2 раза их нужно удалить - оставиить только первые 3 элемента с такими значениями. Как то через in_array ? Но как там по нескольким элементам это делать...

```
[0] => 10ПП23-10 
[1] => Перемычка плитная 10 ПП 23-10 
[2] => GARANT
```

Comment: `array_unique(Array, SORT_REGULAR)` удалит дубли

Comment: нужно во вложенном массиве более мелкий массив(ключи 0 и 1) сравнить со всеми по очереди, и так пока каждый с каждым при условии совпадения удалить массив UnSet($value);

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$data=array('210'=>array( 
'0' => '10ПП23-10', 
'1' => 'Перемычка плитная 10 ПП 23-10', 
'2' => 'GARANT'), 
'211' => array( 
'0' => '10ПП30-13', 
'1' => 'Перемычка плитная 10 ПП 30-13', 
'2' => 'GARANT'), 
'212' => array( 
'0' => '1ПБ16-1', 
'1' => 'Перемычка плитная 10 ПП 23-10', 
'2' => 'GARANT'), 
'213' => 
array( 
'0' => '10ПП23-10', 
'1' => 'Перемычка плитная 10 ПП 23-10', 
'2' => 'GARANT'),
'214' => array( 
'0' => '10ПП30-13', 
'1' => 'Перемычка плитная 10 ПП 30-13', 
'2' => 'GARANT')
);
echo "Начальный массив  "."<br>";



function myFunction($a,$b) {
foreach ($a as $key => $value) {

$b=$key;
    for ($tr=210; $tr<=209+count($a); $tr++){
        if($a[$tr][0]==$a[$b][0]){
            $jon[]=$tr;
        }
    }

for ($tr1=1; $tr1<=count($jon)-1; $tr1++){ UnSet($a[$jon[$tr1]]); }
//массив который необходимо удалить из общего =)
}

return $a;

}

$aa=myFunction($data,'210');


foreach ($aa as $key => $value) {
UnSet($data[$key]);

}

print_r($data);

?>
```